# Unable to install VLC on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, vlc

I upgraded to 15.10 from 14 a month or so ago and ended up losing VLC in the process.

Now when I attempt to install VLC

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To find out why libgles1 can't be installed, I attempted to install it

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgles1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgles1-mesa' instead of 'libgles1'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles1-mesa : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 11.0.2-1ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Once again I tried to install the dependency

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Since it was already installed I checked version

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa
libglapi-mesa:
  Installed: 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty
  Candidate: 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.0.2-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

It turns out I have a newer version of libglapi-mesa than wanted by libgles1.

What can I do here? I'm not entirely sure what the apt-cache policy output means but it seems to suggest there is a known 11.0.2 version out there. Should I look at rolling back to it?

---

Update:

The reason I had a newer version of libglapi-mesa was because a while ago I had steam installed and it required me to upgrade libgl1-mesa-glx to 11.0.4, which depended on libglapi-mesa 11.0.4. I have since removed Steam so I decided to roll back the packages to the standard versions.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx=11.0.2-1ubuntu4 libglapi-mesa=11.0.2-1ubuntu4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libqt4-opengl-dev
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 6 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
...
```

VLC now installed fine

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdrm-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau-dev
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-glx0-dev
  libxcb-present-dev libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxshmfence-dev libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm-dev libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-common-dev x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libqt5x11extras5 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-xv0 vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-samba
Suggested packages:
  videolan-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libqt5x11extras5 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-xv0 vlc
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,571 kB of archives.
```

I think perhaps the most interesting thing is that before upgrading to Wily, VLC was working fine with the 11.0.4 versions of libglapi-mesa. I suspect now that VLC is installed, if I needed them again I could upgrade to 11.0.4 without breaking VLC.

Comment: The first question that you might want to answer is "Why do you have a repository for Trusty (14.04) on your Wily (15.10)?" When you answer it, I would suggest that you do a clean install of 15.10 and avoid adding (clearly harmful) external repositories.

Comment: The defacto "clean install" answer is not acceptable. It's also not acceptable to pretend you can avoid adding external repositories. Vanilla Ubuntu doesn't have every program I will ever need.

Comment: I do appreciate you finding the 'trusty' keyword which I had missed.

Comment: Well, until now you just pointed out VLC, which is there. And is has the right dependencies in Ubuntu's repos. If you really need to have this external repository enabled, there is no solution. Since probably one of the packages you install from there will need to use a newer version of the library, than the one needed by VLC, creating a non-solvable situation in which you need two packages that need two different versions of a common dependency.

Comment: I think the issue may have been a result of Steam requiring a different version of libGL.so than what was available. I have since removed steam. I'm not sure how I can revert the damage done however.

Comment: If using the xorg-edgers ppa (and a couple of others like it) you really should run ppa-purge on the ppa Before doing an upgrade to a new Ubuntu release. Probably says so on the ppa page..

Comment: @user276318 I don't think it's Steam. I have Steam on my machine and I did not need to add that `ricotz` repository. You *really should* keep track of what repositories you really need and what not. And during time get rid of the ones you do not need.

Comment: @dadexix86 I'm fairly certain it was a combination of Steam and my Nvidia graphics driver. With some missing 32-bit libraries.

Comment: @doug Yes, I noticed after the upgrade that trying to purge Trusty ppa's didn't behave as I expected. Actually I somewhat expected the repositories in sources.list.d to attempt to upgrade along with Ubuntu. However the Software Manager had all those PPA's listed as disabled.